# Is "program.exe param:value param2:value" a good format for Windows command line applications?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

Today I have seen a command-line arguments format to a Windows application, it was like

```
program.exe format:xml input:some-file.xml output:other-file.xml
```

I know that some Windows programs (developed by Microsoft or third parties) use `/key value /key2 value2` format for cmd-line arguments. So is this colon notation also an acceptable notation or did that guy just made this up?

What is the convention? (or is there no convention at all?)

Comment: I don't think this will end up being a constructive question, so I'll answer as a comment:  Strictly speaking from personal experience, that doesn't seem like a standard notation. I could, however, see it being used if you want to allow the parameters to be entered in any order, and then parse them out based on the parameter key. But why bother?

Comment: Some Microsoft SDK tools use a colon as well, particularly the .NET build tools.  A programmer just picks what he likes.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables here's why bother, there is no standard or convention in Microsoft ecosystem. On the other hand UNIX ecosystem is just well designed and the experience of using different UNIX programs are seamless and you can learn quickly due to standards. I always know `-h` and `--help` will show help, `-v` or `--version` will show the version etc. This is designed for humans, this is why it bothers me.